# How can I compare a mysql table between two databases and update the differences efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the setup, I have multiple online stores that I would like to use the same product database. Currently they are all separate, so updating anything requires going through and copying products over, it is a giant pain. What I would like to do is create a master product database that every night, each site will compare its database with, and make updates accordingly.

The idea is one master database of products that will be updated a few times a day, and then say at 2:00 AM, a cron job will run pulling the updates to the individual websites.

Just a few more details on the database, there is one table 'products' that needs to be compared, but it also needs to look at table 'prodcuts_site_status' to determine the value for the products status for each given site, so I can't simply dump the master table and re-important it into the site databases.

Creating a php script to go row by row and compare and update would be easy enough, but I was hoping there existed a more elegant/efficient solution in mysql. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: When you are talking about multiple databases are you talking about physically separated servers or different databases in the same MySQL server?

Comment: And what about using [MySQL replication capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036299/how-do-i-keep-two-article-tables-synced-but-keep-stock-separate for a similar question.

Comment: You can save the query results of your cron job from your master database to the individual one. See http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/158-how-to-save-query-results-in-a-mysql-table/

Comment: Yes, the servers are physically separated.

Comment: If your servers are physically separated you might be interested in either "replication" or "ETL". I suggest DVK's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570877/perl-how-to-copy-mirror-remote-mysql-tables-to-another-database-possibly-dif

Comment: You can also try FEDERATED storage engine to join tables from different servers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I think replication is going to work just fine! I will have to alter the platform code slightly to pull the product_status from a different location, but that is a small enough change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up you could try 3 different methods:

1. use  `SELECT` ... `INTO OUTFILE` and then `LOAD DATA INFILE` from [MySQL Cross Server Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query)
2. use the **replication approach** described here [Perl: How to copy/mirror remote MYSQL table(s) to another database? Possibly different structure too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570877/perl-how-to-copy-mirror-remote-mysql-tables-to-another-database-possibly-dif)
3. use a `FEDERATED` **storage engine** to join tables from different servers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html